# Is there any way to run x64 vm without virtualization Technology support?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I have Intel CPU without VT support. How can I run x64 vm on this?

Comment: What CPU are you on? Is it 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: Intel Core2 Quad Q8200

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a X86-64/EM64T CPU then you can use VirtualBox or recent VMware products, otherwise you can use QEMU. Lack of hardware support does not mean that you cannot use virtualization at all.